# Vue Checkbox get an array value but want Array of JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

[image]

```html
<checkbox-group @change="checkboxChange">
                <label class="uni-list-cell uni-list-cell-pd" v-for="item in items" :key="item.value">
                    <view>
                        <checkbox :value="item.value" :checked="item.checked" />
                    </view>
                    <view>{{item.name}}</view>
                </label>
            </checkbox-group>
```

The data variable from the checkbox is

```html
items: [
        {
           value: 'USA',
           name: 'American'
        },

         {
           value: 'JPN',
           name: 'Japan'
         },
         {
           value: 'ENG',
           name: 'England'
         },
         {
           value: 'FRA',
           name: 'France'
         }
 ]
```

When check the box for selecting different countries, will get this value.
["JPN", "ENG"]

```html
checkboxChange: function(e) {
                var items = this.items,
                      values = e.detail.value; 
            
                console.log(values) #get value ["JPN", "ENG"]
}
```

But the desired result is Array of JSON Objects like below

```html
new_items: [ 
       {
         value: 'JPN',
         name: 'Japan'
       },
       {
         value: 'ENG',
         name: 'English'
       }
]
```

How can I use this value ["JPN", "ENG"] to map with checkbox items to get new_items?

Comment: Please show the `checkbox` element and how is it bound?

Comment: I posted @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: which UI framework are you using?

Comment: Is not global UI framework it for SuperApp and miniApp only 
And The result value I think it can convert array to Array of JSON Objects right? @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: try out `<checkbox :value="item" :checked="item.checked" />`

Comment: it worked, Is it that easy? haha I didn't look at the code well. @BoussadjraBrahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the whole object to the `value` prop :

```
<checkbox :value="item" :checked="item.checked" />
```